# Not able to get physical camera's id when there are multiple cameras in a device android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I'm using the Camera2 Api in my app designed for the Samsung S21. This mobile has 3 rear cameras and a front camera.
And I'm trying to choose the physical camera used, but the function
`getPhysicalCameraIds()`  always returns an empty array.
Is there another way to get the `PhysicalCameraIds` or specify which camera to use??
Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please share your code here so that people can see that and then reply

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#getPhysicalCameraIds())?

Comment: @KaranMehta i'm trying to use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the physical cameras are exposed via logical cameraID.
Query the current cameraID's list and check if you can find any logical cameraID.
For a logical cameraID you can query list of physical cameraID it supports.

Comment: He is doing same thing and asking WHY RETURNS EMPTY ARRAY WHILE DEVICE HAS 3 BACKCAMERA.